# Mysql: Grouping three rows together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three rows that look like this

```
merchant    col1    col2    col3    col4
Al's        1       0        0      0
Al's        0       2        0      0
Al's        0       0        3      0
Al's        0       0        0      4
```

And I want to turn it into:

```
merchant    col1    col2    col3    col4
Al's        1       2        3      4
```

As i've tried to achieve the above, I tried to group it by merchant. when I do:

```
group by merchant
```

At the end of the query, I get this result

```
merchant    col1    col2    col3    col4
Al's        1       0        0      0
```

So basically the first row only. Is there any way to accomplish what I need? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
select merchant,max(col1),max(col2),max(col3)..
from yourtable
group by merchant
```

or If the other values will always be zero then

```
select merchant,sum(col1),sum(col2),sum(col3)..
from yourtable
group by merchant
```

Comment: Wonderful! Just what I needed. Thank you.